# Array to view output Laravel JSON

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-blade

at the moment I use the following function to respond data to view

```
public function getSpiel(){
        $spiel = Input::get('spieleID');
        $teamOutput = Spielplan::where('Spielplan_ID', '=', $spiel)->get();
/*
        $heimName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $teamOutput->Heimmannschaft)->first();
        $gastName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $teamOutput->Gastmannschaft)->first();
        $shop = array(
            array($teamOutput->Spielplan_ID, $heimName ),
            array($teamOutput->Spielplan_ID,  $gastName)
        );
*/
        return Response::json($teamOutput);
```

Now, I need to change the input array? At the comment lines is the new logic. 
How can I put the new array $shop into return Response::json($shop)? And how can I use the three fields in the view?
There I have a java script function and at the moment I use fields like this.

```
$.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){
                $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + valueAusData.Heimmannschaft + '">'+valueAusData.Heimmannschaft+'</option>');
                $('#spiel').append('<option value="' + valueAusData.Gastmannschaft + '">'+valueAusData.Gastmannschaft+'</option>');
            });
```

In Spielplan_ID and in > //Here I need $heimName

Answer (score 0):

You can return both arrays in json:

```
return Response::json(['team'=>$teamOutput, 'shop'=>$shop]);
```

Then, parse and use the json in javascript.

Or, you can pass the arrays to view in your response

```
return view('view_name', ['team'=>$teamOutput, 'shop'=>$shop]);
```

Then, in view file use the values of the arrays from `$team` and `$shop`.

Comment: Thank you. For me  is not clear what are the values of $shop. In the java script part I use valueAusData./*AND WHAT COMES HERE*/

Comment: If it is an Ajax request, `data.team` should contain the array from `$teamOutput`, and `data.shop` should contain the array from `$shop`.

Comment: What excatly does ::json do? Do I really need this? When I only want to send an array to a view?

Comment: Generally, JSON is used for Ajax Requests, or external applications. You not need json to send array to view.